# how to change Samsung keyboard size limit

Tags: root, xposed, samsung

The Samsung keyboard resize has a certain size limit, while I've a custom layout set by Keyscafe I need more row. I've root access.

I tried to use the built in resize function it is limited to a certain height.
I tried to change some values inside /data/user/0/com.samsung.android.honeyboard/shared_prefs/com.samsung.android.honeyboard_preferences.xml
But didn't work